# problems with shell script

Tags: shell, ksh

i am somewhat forced to use an environmet i am really not used to.
I have a large prepare script that generates a jobscript for our cluster. I stripped out a minimal example that shows what is not working right now.

```
#! /bin/ksh

EXPDIR="/home/user1/tmp/exp"
EXPNO="${testno}"

if [ ! -d "$EXPDIR" ]; then
    /client/bin/mkdir -p "${EXPDIR}"
    cd "${EXPDIR}"
fi

jobname="${jobname:-${EXPNO}}"
jobfile="${jobfile:-${EXPDIR}/${jobname}.job}"


cat >"${jobfile}" <<EOF1



#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# TEST 
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This script should create a file called `testno.job` containing

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# TEST 
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

in the directory `/home/user1/tmp/exp` and create the directory if it is not existing. The only problem is that the file is not called `testno.job` but `.job`. Can you help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, the `jobfile` variable contains `.job` rather than `testno.job`. I think you need to set `testno` because it is used to produce the `jobname` variable.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, you haven't defined the ${testno} variable.